# What is the probability that a ﬁve-card poker hand contains "four of a kind hand"?

Tags: probability

### Question

What is the probability that a ﬁve-card poker hand contains "four of a kind hand"?

For More information about poker's **four of a kind hand**,please refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability)

### My Attempt

$\text {Rank of card-: Jack,King,Queen,Ace}$$,9,8,...1$

In **four of a kind hand** , $4$ cards are of the same rank( and obviously of diiferent type)

$\Rightarrow$ Now in a set of $52$ card,we have $13$ ranks of $4$ kind(spade,heart,diamond,club)

$\Rightarrow$ **four of a kind hand** says  $4$ cards are of the same rank.

So Among $13$ ranks ,select $1$ of the rank i.e $\binom{13}{1}$,

and the remaining last card can be any thing

I am not getting how to move forward ,please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the remaining card can be anything. But you still need to count it. In how many ways can that happen?

> You could approach it in the same manner. First count the number of ways to choose the rank. Then count the number of ways to choose one of the suits. Alternatively, ignore all that and just choose one of the remaining cards. This can be done in $\binom{48}{1} = \binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1} = 48$ ways. Then remember to divide by $\binom{52}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{13\times(52-4)}{\left( \begin{array}{cc}{52}\\{5}\end{array}\right)}\simeq 0.024\%$$

First, we have 13 possibilities of "four of a kind".  Once that's picked, we have 48 cards remaining, and any one may be picked.  So there're $13\times 48$ possible combinations.  Dividing this by the total possible hands, i.e. $\left(\begin{array}{cc}52 \\ 5\end{array}\right)$, gives the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve this using the hypergeometric probability distribution, whose probability mass function is:
$$
P(Y = y) = \frac{\binom{r}{y} \cdot \binom{N - r}{n - y}}{\binom{N}{n}}
$$

with $N$ being the population total, $n$ the sampled population, $r$ the number of "successes" in the total population (ie, the kind of element we are trying to track among the many in $N$), and $y$ is the number of successes out of sample $n$, that we want to compute the probability of.

In the case of a poker hand, using a deck without wildcards:

- $N = 52$ number of cards in the deck;
- $n = 5$ a hand of 5 cards;
- $r = 4$ there are 4 cards inside the deck for each of the values $A, 2, 3, \dots, 10, J, Q, K$;
- $y = 4$ we are tracking a four-of-a-kind hand.

From the hypergeometric probability mass formula above we obtain:

$$
P(Y = 4) = \frac{\binom{4}{4} \cdot \binom{52 - 4}{5 - 4}}{\binom{52}{5}} = \frac{1 \cdot 48}{2,598,960} = 0.001846892 \%
$$

The above is the probability of getting a hand with a four-of-a-kind of a specific value. But there are 13 possible values among all the cards, so we multiply the result obtained above from the hypergeometric distribution by 13 and finally we get to

$$
13 \cdot 0.001846892 \% = 0.024009603 \%
$$

which is the same result of the other answers.